# Avoiding code repetition in C++ (partial) template specialization

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class Vector which represents a mathematical vector of a given template class. I want to be able to save the vectors in two different ways:

```
template <class T>
class Vector
{
private:
    T* elements;
};
```

and

```
template <class T, unsigned int D>
class Vector
{
private:
    T elements[D];
};
```

In the first example I allocate and free the array with new and delete in constructor and destructor.
Now since I don't want to write all the methods twice for both classes, and since it wouldn't even compile this way because I have two classes with the same name but different template arguments, I would like to combine both classes into one class like so:

```
template <class T, int D = -1>
class Vector
{
public:
    Vector<T, D> add(const Vector<T, D>& add) const;
private:
    T elements[D];
};

template <class T>
class Vector<T, -1>
{
public:
    Vector<T, D> add(const Vector<T, D>& add) const;
private:
    T* elements;
};
```

So the second part is just a partial template specialization of the first one. If no dimensions are given the dynamically allocated option should be used (default argument for D). As an example I added a function to calculate the sum of two vectors. 
Now my problem is that I have to give two implementations for what is logically just one function. Whenever I access the *elements* array it's exactly the same syntax in the dynamic and in the static Vector class. Can I somehow combine both implementations into just one implementation of the add function (and likewise of all similar functions)?
If I cannot solve the problem this way, do you have other ideas of how to create the Vector class with both dynamic and static memory allocation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go for a policy-based design, similar to the way how `std::vector` handles allocation.

In your case it means:

- Define a class which stores the vector elements but only provides a minimal interface. (**Policy**)
- Define your vector interface independent of the way the elements are stored in the policy. It accesses the elements in a way independent of that implementation. The policy class should be added as a template type parameter (which can have a default value), so the user of your vector class can choose which policy to use. **Inherit from the policy class** or add a member of its type (privately if you don't want to expose the policy interface in the public interface).

Example (here with aggregation instead of inheritance):

```
// The policy default implementation:
template <class T, int D>
class VectorStorage
{
    T elements[D];
public:
    T& operator[](int x) {
        return elements[x];
    }
    const T& operator[](int x) const {
        return elements[x];
    }
};
class VectorStorage<T, -1>
{
    T* elements; // (for allocation, see below)
public:
    T& operator[](int x) {
        return elements[x];
    }
    const T& operator[](int x) const {
        return elements[x];
    }
};


// The vector implementation, independent of the storage,
// but defaulting to the one above:
template <class T, int D = -1, class Storage = VectorStorage<T,D>>
class Vector
{
    Storage storage;
public:
    Vector<T, D> add(const Vector<T, D>& add) const {
        // Access your elements using "storage[x]"
    }
};
```

Note that you need a suitable constructor for your policy class (as in the case of the dynamic storage type, you need the size during construction). Provide a unique constructor interface to all of your specializations, not only for the one which need it; and call the constructor in the vector's constructor appropriately:

```
// within class VectorStorage<T,-1>:
VectorStorage(int size) : elements(new T[size]) {}
~VectorStorage() { delete[] elements; }
// within class VectorStorage<T,D>:
VectorStorage(int /* ignored */) {}
```

```
// within class Vector:
Vector(int size) : storage(size) {}
```

Alternatively, to support client code like `Vector<int,5> myVector;` (i.e. default constructor on the static size version), provide a default constructor which is only allowed to be called for the static size version:

```
Vector() : storage(D) {
    static_assert(D != -1, "The default constructor is only allowed for the static-sized version of Vector.");
}
```

Now a user can even use `Vector` with `std::vector` as the storage back-end: `Vector<int, -1, std::vector<int>>` or `Vector<int, 5, std::vector<int>>`. Or even `Vector<int, 5, std::array<int,5>>`.

Comment: For using a `std::vector` as the storage class wouldn't the user need a way to set the size? You can't just use the `std::vector`'s [] operator without resizing first.

Comment: @Fsmv Of course, but the same holds for `VectorStorage<T,-1>`. I think OP left out the initialization part, which I now added to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, that solution is pretty nice!

Comment: Better to use `std::unique_ptr` (or `std::vector`) instead of raw owning pointer. and unless you choose `std::vector`, you have to write the copy/move constructor/assignment (Rule of 5).

Comment: @Jarod42 True, but OP said he already has code for that (I only showed it to make it clear how to forward the constructors). So your comment better fits under the question.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like the following, i.e specialize only the data part:

```
template <class T, int D = -1>
class VectorData
{
public:
    int size() const { return D; }

protected:
    T elements[D];
};

template <class T>
class VectorData<T, -1>
{
public:
    explicit VectorData(int size) : elements(size) {}

    int size() const { return elements.size(); }

protected:
    std::vector<T> elements;
};


template <class T, int D = -1>
class Vector : protected VectorData<T, D>
{
public:
    using VectorData<T, D>::VectorData;
    Vector add(const Vector& add) const
    {
        Vector res(*this);

        for (int i = 0; i != this->size(); ++i) {
            res.elements[i] += add.elements[i];
        }
        return res;
    }
};
```

Comment: Why do you use `-1` as a value for specialization instead of simple `0`?

Comment: @Constructor You should ask this the OP, as he did that in his code.

Comment: OP uses `-1`, I would also prefer `0`.

Comment: Thanks as well. I used -1 because a zero-dimensional vector is theoretically possible and even useful for some mathematical applications.

Comment: Array of size `0` is not possible in standard C++ (maybe with some extension).

Comment: @leemes, Jarod42 I wasn't paying attention to the OP code, sorry.